# compounding yearly interest using tsql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to create a table as such using sql for compounding interest.

```
name    rate    principal   year1   year2
A       .5      10          15       22.5
B       .0      10          10       10.0
```

I am able to create a stored procedure and hardcode it for two years of interest for each name but that means that every additional year I have to add another year. Is there an elegant and efficient way for doing this using procedure(s) or just views?

Comment: You can create a child table (1 to many) to store the multiple year, amount against each 'name'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to need a compound interest calculation and a pivot. Here's a static version for 5 years, there are plenty of examples of dynamic pivoting on SO if you need to make the duration dynamic.

**Edit:**  I overlooked the SQL 2005 tag - can't confirm this will work on that version as we're SQL 2012/4 here.

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (
    Name CHAR(1),
    Rate MONEY,
    Principal MONEY
);

INSERT INTO #Test (Name, Rate, Principal)
VALUES  ('A', 0.5, 10),('B', 0, 10);


WITH Years AS (
 SELECT 1 Year
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT Year+1 FROM Years
 WHERE Year < 5
)
SELECT
     *
       FROM 
    (SELECT 'Year'+CAST(Year AS VARCHAR(1)) Year, 
        Name, 
        Rate, 
        Principal,   
        Principal * POWER((Rate+1), Year) Result
    FROM Years, #Test) A
PIVOT (MAX(RESULT) FOR YEAR IN ([Year1], [Year2], [Year3],[Year4],[Year5])) PVT


Name Rate                  Principal             Year1                 Year2                 Year3                 Year4                 Year5
---- --------------------- --------------------- --------------------- --------------------- --------------------- --------------------- ---------------------
A    0.50                  10.00                 15.00                 22.50                 33.75                 50.625                75.938
B    0.00                  10.00                 10.00                 10.00                 10.00                 10.00                 10.00
```

Answer (score -2):

Is below what you want?

```
declare @NbrofYears int, @Rate float, @Principle float

select @NbrofYears = 5, @Principle = 10, @rate = 0.5

;with cte as
(
select 1 as NbrOfYears, @Principle as Principle, @Rate as Rate
union all
select NbrOfYears + 1, Principle * (1 + @Rate), Rate
from cte
where NbrOfYears < @NbrofYears
)

select * from cte
```

Comment: There is a closed formula for accumulated amount of compound interest - use it instead of an inefficient recursive CTE.